# Jquery how to get the value of every li by onclick

Tags: jquery, css

i have 3 image to show, the image is inside the li, and i put value on every li the value of the li correspond the width of the window. for example if i get the the first value of li index 0 the first image will show..etc. here my code

```
<div class="sliderContainer">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide" value="0">img</li>
    <li class="slide" value="1366">img</li>
    <li class="slide" value="2732">img</li>
  </ul>

  <a class="next"><img src="images/sliderArrowleft.png" /></a>
  <a class="prev"><img src="images/sliderArrowright.png" /></a>  
</div>
```

If i will click the .next btn, it must get the li value 1366 then if i click .next btn again it will get 2732 and loop again from 0, 1366, 2732 and loop again...... please help me...

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's what you're looking for :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var values = [],
    index = 0,
    items = $('.slide').length;

  $(".slide").each(function(index) {
    values.push($(this).val());
  });

  $('.prev').click(function() {
    var tmp = index--;
    if (tmp <= 0) index = items;
    console.log('Switch to slide n°' + index);
  });

  $('.next').click(function() {
    var tmp = index++;
    if (tmp >= items) index = 0;
    console.log('Switch to slide n°' + index);
  });

});
```

**What's cool:** It'll work regardless of the number of slides you have !

Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/4405/

My way is a bit more verbose and isn't using `prev()` and `next()` as Mehul Mohan did, but it's quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentLI = $('.slides li:first-child');
$('a.next').click(function() {
  currentLI.next();
  if(!currentLI.length) currentLI = $('.slides li:first-child');
  // use currentLI
});

$('a.prev').click(function() {
  currentLI.prev();
  if(!currentLI.length) currentLI = $('.slides li:last-child');
  // use currentLI
});
```

Use jQuery `prev()` and `next()`